# How to merge arrays to one array kind of respectively in ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to combine the arrays together to add the first column of all arrays, then the second columns, respectively, to the end.

My arrays :

```
[1,2,3,4,5] 

[6,7,8,9,10]

[11,12,13,14,15]
```

i want result :

```
[1,6,11 , 2,7,12 , 3,8,13 , 4,9,14 , 5,10,15]
```

Comment: Are your arrays always the same size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5] 
b = [6,7,8,9,10]
c = [11,12,13,14,15]

((a.zip b).zip c).flatten.compact
=> [1, 6, 11, 2, 7, 12, 3, 8, 13, 4, 9, 14, 5, 10, 15]
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work if arrays have different size.

Comment: Why do you use `compact`? And your use of parenthesis is very unusual. `a.zip(b).zip(c).flatten.compact` would be better.

Comment: Also you can write `a.zip(b, c).flatten`.

Comment: If `a.length > b.length`, the `.zip` method produces nil values and `.compact` removes them. `a = [1,2]` `b = [3] ` `a.zip(b).flatten.compact => [1,3,2]`

Comment: Okay fair enough, but add this explanation to your answer since `compact` makes no difference to your example because the arrays are all the same length. Also what if `a.size < b.size`?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have a "simple" case where the three arrays are the same length:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5] 
b = [6,7,8,9,10]
c = [11,12,13,14,15]
```

In this case, you can use [`Array#zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-zip) to merge the arrays in your desired way, then flatten the result into a single array:

```
a.zip(b, c).flatten
  #=> [1, 6, 11, 2, 7, 12, 3, 8, 13, 4, 9, 14, 5, 10, 15]
```

---

However, what if `a.length > b.length` or `b.length > c.length`?

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5] 
b = [6,7,8,9]
c = [10,11,12]
```

This is a little bit harder, because now `Array#zip` will leave you with some `nil` values that you presumably want to remove:

```
a.zip(b, c).flatten
  #=> [1, 6, 10, 2, 7, 11, 3, 8, 12, 4, 9, nil, 5, nil, nil]

a.zip(b, c).flatten.compact
  #=> [1, 6, 10, 2, 7, 11, 3, 8, 12, 4, 9, 5]
```

---

And finally, what if `a.length < b.length` or `b.length < c.length`?

```
a = [1,2,3] 
b = [4,5,6,7]
c = [8,9,10,11,12]
```

This is again a bit harder. Now, you'll presumably want to **pad** the arrays with as many `nil`s as needed, and then perform the same operation as above:

```
max_length = [a,b,c].map(&:length).max

def padded_array(array, size)
  array.dup.fill(nil, array.length, size)
end

padded_array(a, max_length).zip(
  padded_array(b, max_length), padded_array(c, max_length)
).flatten.compact
```

So the complexity of your final answer depends on what arrays you are dealing with, and how far you need to go with accounting for edge cases.